# SQL cursor issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cursor

I am trying to create a new table using a cursor and a select statements.

```
 Declare
     Cursor c1 is 
     select store_number from table1  where CLIENT_ID= 1 and ORG_ID = 1 ;

     Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of c1%ROWTYPE;      
     c1_list c1_TAB_TYPE;

       Begin     
           For r1 in c1 

           Loop
            select  store_number
               BULK COLLECT INTO c1_list from

                (
                 SELECT store_number,
                ( (SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(a.geometry,b.geometry, 0.005), 0.005, 'unit=sq_mile') /SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA((a.geometry), 0.005, 'unit=sq_mile'))*100) Total_area
                 FROM table2 a, table1 b
                 Where store_number != r1.store_number
                 AND sdo_relate(a.geometry, b.geometry, 'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE');

                   For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                                 insert into temp_Prop_area
                 (STORE_NUMBER,TOTAL_AREA)
                  values (r1.store_number,Total_Area);

                   End Loop;
             End Loop;

 End;
```

Here I am using a store number to pass into a cursor.Now once have a store number ,I check want to get the area of overlapping between polygon for each store and the small polygons from table 1 over which the stores overlay. That area is called as Total_area. I am trying to pass this store number and total area in to the temp_Prop_area table.

But I wont be able to do since in my cursor type I just have store_number . So what could I be doing to fix this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand what you're doing, but the issue seems to be that your `c1_list` doesn't have a column to put the `Total_Area`? If so you can force that by selecting a dummy column in your cursor:

```
 Declare
     Cursor c1 is 
     select store_number, 0 as total_area
      from table1  where CLIENT_ID= 1 and ORG_ID = 1 ;

     Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of c1%ROWTYPE;      
     c1_list c1_TAB_TYPE;
```

Then you can just select into that:

```
...
           Loop
            select  store_number, total_area
               BULK COLLECT INTO c1_list from
...

                   For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                                 insert into temp_Prop_area
                 (STORE_NUMBER,TOTAL_AREA)
                  values (c1_list(i).store_number,c1_list(i).Total_Area);
                   End Loop;
             End Loop;
 End;
```

But you aren't taking advantage of bulk inserts, which is a shame as you are already using `bulk collect`. If you define the collection based on your new table then you can use `forall`.

```
 Declare
     Cursor c1 is 
     select store_number
      from table1  where CLIENT_ID= 1 and ORG_ID = 1 ;

     Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of temp_prop_area%ROWTYPE;      
     c1_list c1_TAB_TYPE;
...
           Loop
            select  store_number, total_area
               BULK COLLECT INTO c1_list from
...
                   Forall i in 1..c1_list.count
                      insert into temp_Prop_area
                      values c_list(i);
             End Loop;
 End;
```

This assumes your `temp_prop_area` only has those two columns, in that order; if not you'll need to adjust the `select` to pull dummy values for any other columns.

Answer (score 0):

As per you suggestions here is the following block.
     Declare
        Cursor c1 is 
        select store_number ,0 as total_area 
        from TMCS.TMCS_All_Stores_TA  where CLIENT_ID= 1 and ORG_ID = 1 ;

```
    Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of c1%ROWTYPE;      
    c1_list c1_TAB_TYPE;

      Begin     
          For r1 in c1 

          Loop
           select  store_number,total_area
              BULK COLLECT INTO c1_list from

               (
                SELECT store_number,
               ( (SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(a.geometry,b.geometry, 0.005), 0.005, 'unit=sq_mile') /SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA((a.geometry), 0.005, 'unit=sq_mile'))*100) Total_area
                FROM TMCS.TMCS_BG_STI_DATA a, TMCS.TMCS_All_Stores_TA b
                Where store_number != r1.store_number
                AND sdo_relate(a.geometry, b.geometry, 'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE');

                  For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                            insert into TMCS.temp_Prop_area
                            values c1_list(i);

                  End Loop;
            End Loop;

End;
```

Now in the last part I actually wanted them to split in two tables.One table will have all the values which have total_area as 100 and the other table will have the rest which are not 100. So could it be like or could it be more fine tuned

```
              if  total_area=100
               then                
                  For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                            insert into TMCS.temp_Prop_area_100
                            values c1_list(i);

                  End Loop;
                  else if 
                  For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                            insert into TMCS.temp_Prop_area_block
                            values c1_list(i);
```