# Multiple cursors in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cursor, oracle-spatial

I have to deal with three tables having geometries.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
      store_number,
      0 AS total_area,
      0 AS bg_id,
      0 AS store_geom
    FROM table1 WHERE client_id = 1 AND org_id = 1;

  TYPE c1_tab_type IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
  c1_list c1_tab_type;

BEGIN

  FOR r1 IN c1
  LOOP

    SELECT bg_id, store_number, total_area
    BULK COLLECT INTO c1_list
    FROM (
        SELECT
          bg_id,
          store_number,
          b.geometry                                                       store_geom,
          ((sdo_geom.SDO_AREA(sdo_geom.SDO_INTERSECTION(a.geometry, b.geometry, 0.005), 0.005, 'unit=sq_mile') /
            sdo_geom.SDO_AREA((a.geometry), 0.005, 'unit=sq_mile')) * 100) total_area
        FROM table2 a, table1 b
        WHERE store_number != r1.store_number
              AND sdo_relate(a.geometry, b.geometry, 'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE');

    IF total_area = 100 THEN
      FOR i IN 1..c1_list.count LOOP
        INSERT INTO temp_prop_area_100 VALUES c1_list(i);
      END LOOP;
    ELSE IF
      FOR i IN 1..c1_list.count LOOP
        INSERT INTO temp_Prop_area_block VALUES c1_list(i);
      END LOOP;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

So I select a record(the biggest geometry of all three tables) from table 1 and overlay over smaller polygons from table 2. I get the list of the overlapping geometries from table 2. This may have a few of them intersecting and a few of them completely under the polygon from table 1.

Then I want to put them in to two different tables . The ones that are completely under in temp_prop_area and the ones which intersect in temp_prop_area_block.

Now the issue I am having is, when I get the id's for all intersecting polygons(temp_prop_area_block)  I want to overlay each of this polygon over the polygons from table 3 which area smaller polygons.And similarly find out which polygons do they intesect and what is the area of intersection.

The polygon size are in this order polygons from table 1 as the biggest, the from table 2 or temp_prop_area_block and then the polygons from table 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. `total_area` doesn't exist outside the record type you've defined, so you can't use it in an `if` where you've shown, but you can just adjust that slightly:

```
...
                  For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                       if c1_list(i).total_area=100
                          then                   
                            insert into temp_Prop_area_100
                            values c1_list(i);
                       else
                            insert into temp_Prop_area_block
                            values c1_list(i);
                       end if;
                  End Loop;
            End Loop;
End;
```

Or you can split your list into two:

```
   Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of c1%ROWTYPE;      
   c1_list c1_TAB_TYPE;
   c1_list_100 c1_TAB_TYPE;
   c1_list_block c1_TAB_TYPE;
...
                  For i in 1..c1_list.count loop
                       if c1_list(i).total_area=100
                          then                   
                            c1_list_100.extend();
                            c1_list_100(c1_list_100.last) := c1_list(i);
                       else
                            c1_list_block.extend();
                            c1_list_block(c1_list_block.last) := c1_list(i);
                       end if;
                  End Loop;

                  For i in 1..c1_list_100.count loop
                       insert into temp_Prop_area_100
                       values c1_list_100(i);
                  End Loop;
                  For i in 1..c1_list_block.count loop
                       insert into temp_Prop_area_block
                       values c1_list_block(i);
                  End Loop;
            End Loop;
End;
```

Which looks like its adding extra complexity for not much gain, which is maybe true if you continue to use individual inserts. But that also allows you to use the `forall` syntax mentioned in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056027/266304):

```
    Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of temp_prop_area%ROWTYPE;      
...
                  Forall i in 1..c1_list_100.count
                       insert into temp_Prop_area_100
                       values c1_list_100(i);
                  Forall i in 1..c1_list_block.count
                       insert into temp_Prop_area_block
                       values c1_list_block(i);
            End Loop;
End;
```

You could also do separate `select ... bulk collect` statements into the two lists, with different filters, but that involves hitting the tables twice and is likely to be less efficient.